# App Idea Force Contact Pull Android

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have an idea for an but I am not sure if it's even possible.  I ran into an issue the other day where a phones touch screen was barley working and I needed to get the contacts off of it. I have a cellbrite machine but anyone who has ever used one knows how finicky they can be.

I would love to develop an android app that will connect to any phone via bluetooth and force pull all the contact from it, this would be handy if you have a troublesome screen. My question is this even possible based on the different phone types, and the different level of bluetooth protocols supported on the phones. If anyone has any ideas on how this might be accomplished hat would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any app with the necessary permission can read a phone's contacts and send them over Bluetooth (or Wi-Fi).

I think the main problem would be that people don't think to install your app until they need it.  Then, you can't install your app onto their broken phone unless the phone has a network connection, and if they have a network connection then there isn't really any need to use Bluetooth in the first place.

Actually, one of the basic ideas of Android is that everything on your phone is sync'ed - so you don't have to worry if your phone gets crushed.

Comment: Tom great info I guess I may have miss communicated, i don't want to have to install it on the target device, Say you have a customer who is upgrading to an android phone from a flip phone, <inset model here> what ever time of phone,I want to be able to intall the app on the new android phone and force the contacts over from the old phone. Hope that helps clarify things

Comment: Oh, OK, that makes more sense.  I don't know what protocols the feature phones support for pulling contacts via Bluetooth.  One problem you would have is that this would require pairing and it would be hard to pair the phones if the old phone has a broken screen.  The other problem is that Android apps have just a basic Bluetooth API - not much power, so not very likely they could do what was necessary to talk to the feature phone.